# How to avoid dictionary items ordering keys randomly?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I've written a function to take excel columns and put them into a dictionary for outputting into json. When I write the json output the key values appear to be randomly ordered. Is there a way I can enforce the key values to be in the order that I add them?

```
def excel_to_json(filename):
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
    sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

    # List to hold dictionaries
    c_list = []

    # Iterate through each row in worksheet and fetch values into dict
    for rownum in range(1, sh.nrows):
        cars = OrderedDict()
        row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)
        cars['Name'] = row_values[0]
        cars['Extensions'] = row_values[1]
        cars['Patterns'] = row_values[2]
        cars['RansomNoteFilenames'] = row_values[3]
        cars['Comment'] = row_values[4]
        cars['EncryptionAlgorithm'] = row_values[5]
        cars['AlternateNames'] = row_values[6]
        cars['Decryptor'] = row_values[7]
        cars['AdditionalInfo1'] = row_values[8]
        cars['AdditionalInfo2'] = row_values[9]
        cars['Screenshots'] = row_values[10]

        c_list.append(cars)

    # Serialize the list of dicts to JSON
    return formatJson(json.dumps(c_list))


def formatJson(input):
    return json.dumps(json.loads(input), indent=4)
```

An example json output looks like the following:

```
 {
        "Name": "dummydata",
        "Comment": "",
        "AlternateNames": "",
        "Screenshots": "dummydata",
        "RansomNoteFilenames": "dummydata",
        "Decryptor": "",
        "Extensions": "dummydata",
        "AdditionalInfo2": "",
        "Patterns": "",
        "EncryptionAlgorithm": "dummydata",
        "AdditionalInfo1": "dummydata",
    },
```

As you can see the keys here are in a different order to the for loop within `excel_to_json()` which makes readability of the json difficult if processed manually.

Comment: You are already using `OrderedDict`. Why are you converting to json again?

Comment: In your formatJson function you are loading it once again (the string to dict) and that causes the problem

Comment: ooops  -deleting....

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use `input` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `input` function.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank-you, good advice!

Comment: @AKS Awesome. I understand now - updating my base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
def formatJson(inp):
    return json.dumps(inp, indent=4)
```

And call it like

```
formatJson(c_list)
```

You are dumping and loading it again an extra time.

Also a slight improvement to your code

```
for rownum in range(1, sh.nrows):
        cars = OrderedDict()
        row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)
        row_names = ['Name','Extensions','Patterns','Comment',....]
        for i in range(len(row_values)):
            cars[row_names[i]] = row_values[i]

        c_list.append(cars)
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on whether the `json` serializer you use actually honors the order within the `OrderedDict`. You could try a different one (e.g. `simplejson`) and see if it works. They are all API compatible.

Also, most `json.dumps` implementations have a `sort_keys` parameter which will sort all keys alphabetically. This is useful when you want to have a *stable* representation of your data, for e.g. diffing, etc.

p.s.

Also, your code can be made much more simple if you use the `zip` builtin.

```
columns = ['Name', 'Extension', 'Patterns']
row = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz']
OrderedDict(zip(columns, row))
```

gives

```
OrderedDict([('Name', 'Foo'), ('Extension', 'Bar'), ('Patterns', 'Baz')])
```